# How to know the process of the terminal which is running in Linux command?

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-mint

In Linux, how can I list the process id in `/proc` folder which is running the current open terminal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the PID of the shell, then it is the `$$` variable, assuming that your shell is `bash` or similar.  Therefore you could use

```
$ ls /proc/$$
```

which would list the contents of that folder for the running shell, or just

```
$ echo $$
```

to see the PID on the screen.

Comment: Can you please explain how this is working?

Comment: In the shell, when you write `$variable` it will substitute in the value of that variable.  There is a special variable named `$$` which is the PID of the shell itself.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this?

```
$ ls /proc/`echo $$`
```